# Create a VCorpus (or VectorSource) with multiple variables?

Tags: r

Im trying to create a Logistic Regression model to predict my target variable, and I have a few explanatory variables to choose from, all of them are text, such as keywords or longer descriptions.

My plan is to make a VectorSource, VCorpus and then a DocumentTermMatrix. During which step in this process should I be adding multiple text variables? As I understand it a DTM will just be a list of common words, so how do I go about comparing multiple variables (different kinds of texts) to create a logistic regression model?

Comment: You can better find a solution to your problem on https://stackexchange.com/